# How can I retrieve userID (INT) depending on username (VARCHAR) from mySQL in JAVA program?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

So, I'm making a login system using **JAVA** and **mySQL**.
And I wanted to retrieve the value of *userID* (int data type), depending on the *username* (string data type).

can someone give me an idea on how to solve this problem, thank you.

here's my table (logindb) structure:

1. Username -- VARCHAR(20)
2. FirstName -- VARCHAR(20)
3. LastName -- VARCHAR(20)
4. userID -- INT(5)

```
public class LoginFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
       
       String username;
       Connection connectDB = null;
       PreparedStatement statementDB = null;

private void buttonLoginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                          
        // TODO add your handling code here:      
        
            try{
                connectDB = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/fyploginsystemdb", "root", "");
                String query = "SELECT `userID` FROM `logindb` WHERE username ='"+username+"'";               
                statementDB = connectDB.prepareStatement(query);
                

            }catch(Exception ex){
                //stuff 
                }
           
        }       
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to read some tutorials, the code block below can be a reference for you, two points needs to pay attention:

1. using `PreparedStatement` to avoid **[sql injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp)**,and in this case you need to pass parameter via `?`
2. using `try-with-resource` if your jdk is above jdk6 to make sure they can close automaticlly

```
public class LoginFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    String username;

    private void buttonLoginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        // TODO add your handling code here:

        String query = "SELECT `userID` FROM `logindb` WHERE username = ? ";
        try (Connection connectDB = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/fyploginsystemdb", "root", "");
             PreparedStatement statementDB = connectDB.prepareStatement(query);) {

            statementDB.setString(1, username);
            try (ResultSet resultSet = statementDB.executeQuery()) {
                while (resultSet.next()) {
                    System.out.println(resultSet.getInt("userID"));
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            //stuff
        }

    }
}
```